# How to convert the byte code to zip file in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, bytecode

Im using the following code to convert the byte code to zip file but it does not download the actual xml and asc file send in the response , instead it just donwloads the standard zip contents , im not aware where i am going wrong , can anyone help me with this,

```
 $http({
    url:url,
    method: requestType,
    data:requestBody?requestBody:"",
    headers: {
       'Content-type': "application/json",
       "SessionID":$rootScope.token
    },
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    let blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/zip"});
    let objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = objectUrl;
    link.download = fileName;
    link.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
    $scope.exp = {}; // to reset the export form after submit.
    $scope.surveyReportdownloading = false;
    $scope.tabActive = false;
 }).error(function (error) {
    //upload failed
    console.log(error);
});
```

this is not downloading the actual files at all. Can anyone help me through this. The byte cod ethat backend team is sending is as follows.

```
"PK:8xJMÆVÞ|xl/workbook.xml ¢( ÍnÂ0ïúÖ>@MpR­¸{C,²vdÑ¾}CR¢¶'n;³³fË«uç£µgöI­ñ«    ¡+8÷²AþÅvhú]mÐKwâ¶®µÄBxEwØ ­ñî<´GX¾s(oµ#6°|~b¬¼5;h¼úAöÆ½îÍd|ñ¿©rMbFVð~!îØ`nT10Wè~Ø4SäiÅÑ,ÇWøÁÿC|¼í¶ëÃzûL/ó4KËYZG0U:üþÂòPK:8xJnmt?Ø[Content_Types].xml ¢( ÅMNÃ0¯y·] vl¡\À²'ÕøGIiÏÆ#q& TUÐªº²lÏ{ßõä·÷é|ãl
mð¥#×ÁX¿,EKU~#æ³éË6f\ê±5Q¼u
```

Na"x¾©Brx2*½RKÑèZêà   <åÔyÙô*Õ6=løxÀ²\dwC]*±±Z_Ëµ7¿ y¨*«ÁÝ:(5¹¦è×Â)ë¯zc¹ Áã _S¬ìk°¶w'~Äd
dèQ9öF¾´êBÙ/ãâ¼ÃîüÿkiÛ>þfå"Çã¿½Sç =ÉÞ']d£áºE
îdþ`s(}Oâ&K\­gJü=x?½wÈþ}PK
38xJ£ ²×rels/.rels ¢( ï»¿PK:8xJILE@¥¶xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml ¢( ¥ÛrÇEÅ÷èn\U\¡\q®ª%^ÿþõË¯ûÃ/·W»Ýñìÿ|"

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are you getting from the server side? zip file or individual files

Comment: im getting the byte code response  which i have written in the question,

Comment: I can understand that you are getting byte code response, but I was asking what exactly that byte code represents?

Comment: oh excuse on that  , they are sending the zip file as byte code , which inturn contains a excel and asc file.  its comming from .net as a file stream.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the issue is with the `type` parameter try with the below code

You can access the `content-type` from `headers`.

If it doesn't work, try with `application/zip, application/octet-stream`

```
$http({
  url: url,
  method: requestType,
  data: requestBody ? requestBody : "",
  headers: {
    'Content-type': "application/json",
    "SessionID": $rootScope.token
  },
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  let blob = new Blob([data], {
    type: headers['content-type']
    //               OR
    // type:"application/zip, application/octet-stream"
  });
  let objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  let link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = objectUrl;
  link.download = fileName;
  link.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
  $scope.exp = {}; // to reset the export form after submit.
  $scope.surveyReportdownloading = false;
  $scope.tabActive = false;
}).error(function(error) {
  //upload failed
  console.log(error);
});

 var blob = new Blob([response.data],{type:headers['content-type']});
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download = "Filename";
  link.click();
```

Comment: It works , a lot of help, but how ironic, its the san evalue that we are giving in the type section too , but it dint work !! Thanks:)